# Stuck more than 2 hrs Angular CDK Drag and Drop - Not able to drop the item in the location

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

Am Struggling lot to complete my task as newly started into Angular CDK DragnDrop. When trying to drag the image item and drop into location, I got **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')** .

Not sure this is because of different Interface against Angular DragnDrop CDK

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data, 
        event.container.data,                              // getting undefined here
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );

      console.log(
        'transferArrayItem',
        event.container.data.colorways
      );

      const formArry = this.myDivName;
      formArry.insert(0, this.fb.control(event.container.data));
    }
  }
```

does event.**container**.data, pointing to *drop location* or *source location*?

[My stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-astsr3-nsspr6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```js
/* Add initial empty data */
imgSource: Pokedex = {
  colorways: [],
  count: 0,
};

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
...
else {
 transferArrayItem(
   event.previousContainer.data,
   event.container.data, //remove colorways, event.container.data?.colorways,
   event.previousIndex,
   event.currentIndex
 );
}
```

```html
<!-- Left container -->
[cdkDropListData]="colorways" <!-- Wrong -->
[cdkDropListData]="colorways.colorways" <!-- Right -->

<!-- Right Container -->
[cdkDropListData]="imgSource" <!-- Wrong -->
[cdkDropListData]="imgSource?.colorways" <!-- Right -->
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-astsr3-nmfrrf?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand the cdkDropList is forget the cdkDropList. We need think simply in two arrays of object

The cdkDropList is only an interface to change the position of the elements of the arrays or to move one element of the array to the another one. We can imagine two simple inputs and three buttons, the first buttons interchange the position of one element in one array and in the another one and the last button interchange the elements of the two arrays

The functions moveItemInArray and transferArrayItem are only javascript function. We can see the definition [this](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts) and we can use or not (*)

The $event that emit an event (cdkDropListDropped) is type of [CdkDragDrop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop), so we have

1. container, the cdkDropList **where is** dropped -so we have in the
   event.container.data  the array we indicate in [data] or the
   cdkDropList
2. previousContainer, idem about the ckdDropList **from** we start drag
3. currentIndex, the index (position) of the element in array
   event.container.data **where is** dropped
4. previousIndex, the index (position) of the element in array of
   event.previousContainer.data

So, the data of your cdkDropList should be colorways.colorways and imgSource.colorways as @Sameer says and you need initialize your obj imgSource

NOTE: use in .html

```
<pre>
{{cdkDropTarget.data|json}}
</pre>
```

To see the array that "store" the cdkDropList "target"

(*) e.g. in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ddxk4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I used the a cdkDropList only to add elements to one array, in this [another one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5qpmg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) drop elements in a CdkDropList to a group of cdkDropList who "data" is an object

Comment: I was expecting you yesterday itself @Eliseo . Now learned DragnDrop in detail Thanks for your time